# Breakup of MEM_LOAD_UOPS_RETIRED.L3_MISS event in Intel Broadwell-EP

Tags: performance, x86, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

I am trying to compare the coherence and DRAM access cost for an application.

For this, I am thinking of measuring L3_MISS (specifically `MEM_LOAD_UOPS_RETIRED.L3_MISS`) events and compare it to HITM events (specifically `MEM_LOAD_UOPS_L3_HIT_RETIRED.XSNP_HITM` and `MEM_LOAD_UOPS_L3_MISS_RETIRED.REMOTE_HITM`).

While looking at the description of the L3_MISS event in perfmon page ([link](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/)) I found the following description:

> Miss in last-level (L3) cache. Excludes Unknown data-source.

Based on this definition I have three questions:

1. Does the above description mean that the L3_MISS event count does not include cross-socket HITM events (since the source is *unknown*)? I couldn't find a more detailed description in the Intel SDM and the 2016 Optimization reference.
2. Speculating further, does this mean that all sub-components of L3_MISS - {LOCAL_DRAM, REMOTE_DRAM, REMOTE_FWD} are also not included in the L3_MISS count?
3. Or am I missing some definition of *unknown data source* in the Intel SDM?

Thanks in advance!

PS: System Info - Broadwell E5 2660v4, Using PAPI to get the performance counter numbers